# I want to know my mistake in the method

Tags: prime-numbers, prime-factorization

Here's the question:

> Let **$N$** be a positive integer, not divisible by **$6$**. Suppose
>   **$N$** has **$6$** positive divisors, the number of positive divisors of **$9N$** is:

I know how approach these questions by adding **$1$** to the powers of the exponent and then multiplying them.

Here the result of the result will be $6*3$ , so the result will be 18 divisors because multiplication of **N** with **$9$** will be **$3^2$** which means extra power $2$.

I want to know where I'm wrong in my  approach towards this concept.

The question has no options.

Comment: For all we know from the question, we could for example have $N = 3 \cdot 5^2$ or $N = 3^2 \cdot 5$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler not necessarily everytime this will be the case, how can you generalise this?

Comment: The problem as stated doesn't have enough information to give a unique answer.  The best we could do, without more context, would be to give a small set of possible answers.

Comment: @DanielSchepler this is the only data given in the question. This is an olympiad question.

Answer (score 2):

If $N$ has $6$ divisors it is of the form $p^2q$ or $p^5$ for $p,q$ prime.  The fact that it is not divisible by $6$ means that at least one of $p,q$ is neither $2$ nor $3$, but that doesn't really help with the problem because we only care about factors of $3$.  $9N$ could now be $3^4q,p^23^3,3^2p^2q, 3^7,\text { or } 3^2p^5$which have $10, 12,18,8\text { and } 18$ divisors respectively.

Added: $N$ could have $0,1,2, \text {or } 5$ factors of $3$.  Adding two more multiplies the number of factors by $3,2,\frac 53, \text { or } \frac 43$ respectively, giving $18,12,10,8$ factors for $9N$

Comment: If $N$ already has $6$ factors that means the product of the exponets (after adding $1$) of the prime factors of $N$ is $6$ and then $9N$ would bring $3^2$ which means the earlier product of exponents $ + 1 * 3$ (since $3^2$) and $2 + 1$ is $3$. Also $3^4$ can be broken down as $3^2 . 3^2 . q$ and hence the number of divisors will be $3 * 3 * 2$ $i.e.$ $18$ . I hope it's readable now.

Comment: Yes, it is readable now, but I don't understand the point.  I added another bit that might help.  $9N$ could have as many as $18$ factors, which would be the case if $N$ has no factors of $3$.  If $N$ does have some factors of $3$ the number of factors of $9N$ will be less.